# canActivate not working with redirected routes in Angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular6

I have my app router file defined with the following content

```
export const router: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'home',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: LandingPageComponent
},
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
},
{
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent
},
{
    path: '404',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
},
{
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
}]
```

When I try navigating to the url `http://localhost:4200/home`, the `AuthGuard` kicks in and the page gets redirected to `http://localhost:4200/login` page.

But when I navigate with url `http://localhost:4200` `redirectTo` kicks in and it directly opens the `http://localhost:4200/home` page instead of the `http://localhost:4200/login` page.

It is supposed to invoke the `AuthGuard` and redirect to `loginPage`, right?

With respect to the following modified route definition, attempting to navigate to `http://localhost:4200` should redirect to `http://localhost:4200/login`, but it opened `http://localhost:4200/home` again

```
{
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: LandingPageComponent
}
```

Is this a bug with Angular 6? Appreciate any help/pointers plz.

My auth.guard.ts file is as follows

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private router: Router) { }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
        // logged in so return true
        return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }}); 
   return false;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you show us your auth-guard?

Comment: i have added it

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the slash:

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',    //<- No slash here
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
```

If that doesn't help, try turning on route tracing to see if that provides any information on why the guard isn't executing.

Comment: No luck. Tried tracing, the logs dont seem to be friendly, did not make much sense to me. However I noted that when guard invokation failed `Router Event: GuardsCheckEnd` had attribute `shouldActivate: true` and false otherwise. And by the way, that was a great tutorial there in Pluralsight. Thanks for that